# Is the warranty period on a hard drive a reliable indicator of its expected service life?

Tags: mybook

I have a WesternDigital MyBook Essential 1TB back up drive.  The warranty was up January 2013.  Does that mean that failure is expected to be imminent and it needs to be replaced immediately?

Comment: This is not answerable, really. It could last a decade or fail the next time you plug it in. Always keep at least two backups.

Comment: The warranty period doesn't really reflect the expected life. Many products come with a warranty period intended only to provide protection against "infant mortality" (failure soon after first use). There are too many variables about how it is installed and used for the manufacturer to deal with long-term warranty claims cost-effectively.  The manufacturers publish MTBF numbers (Mean Time Before Failure in testing), which will give you a better indication than the warranty, although this is inaccurate in real life.

Comment: If it is not an ancient drive, there is a good chance it has SMART technology. This tracks various types of errors and predicts whether a drive is likely in imminent danger of failure due to certain causes (not foolproof, but a good warning when it does detect a problem). However, there are ways a drive can fail suddenly due to causes that are not in the SMART model.  Many people use a rule of thumb that any hard drive in use for more than 5 years is on borrowed time. The key is the Boy Scout motto: "Be prepared". Make regular backups.

Comment: Is your question about shelf life, as in the title (unused drive aging on the shelf--no effect on useful life), or service life as in the question, which was addressed in the responses?

Comment: The reason most HDD manufactures went to a shorter warranty period is indeed the fact because of their own data indicating their products lifespan was shorter than the warranty they did have.  Most of the HDDs unless you "upgrade" the the high-performance or NAS products come with a 2-3 year warranty.  The warranty period does indeed reflect the expected lifespan.  With that said they can fail at any point.

Answer (score 2):

Drive failures are random.

Some drives die ten minutes after you plug them in. Some go on for five, ten years. There's a whole lot in between. It depends on manufacturing design and batches, temperatures, usage patterns, even where you live will affect it.

There's no easy way to predict drive failures. And even if you manage to predict some types of failure, other types can happen without any warning whatsoever.

If you care about your data at all, you need **backups**. That pretty much means storing another copy - the chances of two drives failing simultaneously is considerably lower than a single one. If you want to be safer, you can have an *offline backup* - keep the backup drive unplugged, so it's not wearing down at a similar rate to the primary drive. If you really care about your data, consider having an *offsite backup* - that's a backup stored elsewhere, e.g. at a friend's home, in case of fire or other disaster.

That said, [research](http://research.google.com/archive/disk_failures.pdf) indicates that failure is significantly more likely both in the first three months and after the first two years. That *does not* mean it *can't* fail in between; it's just slightly lower probability.